# What data science programming algorithm is like Naive Bayes for continuous variables?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, naivebayes, data-science

I am trying to build and train a machine learning data science algorithm that correctly predicts what presidential won in what county. I have the following information for training data.

Total population    Median age  % BachelorsDeg or higher    Unemployment rate   Per capita income   Total households    Average household size  % Owner occupied housing    % Renter occupied housing   % Vacant housing    Median home value   Population growth   House hold growth   Per capita income growth    Winner

I am new to data science. I do know Naive Bayes is a good classifier for algorithms trying to predict with multiple properties. However, I read the first step for a naive bayes classifier requires a frequency table. My problem is all of the above properties are continuous numerical properties and don't fall into "Yes" or "No" categories. Do I not use a Naive Bayes classifier then?

I also considered using a k nearest neighbor algorithm, but that doesn't look like it will be the most accurate and weight the properties correctly for me...I am looking for a supervised algorithm because I have training data. Can anyone give me any recommendations as to what algorithm to use? In addition, being new to the field, how can I figure out what algorithm to use on my own in the future.

Comment: This might be more on topic on [computerscience.se]

Comment: I would rather migrate it to stats. Naive bayes is just Bayes Formula with the assumption of feature independence for simplification. It's one of the really pure probabilistic classifiers.

Comment: @cel Do you want me to move my question?/How do I move it?

Comment: I think it fits rather on http://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @moose yes I agree...did not know there was a data science stack exchange. I guess I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: @pr338 - you shouldn't rule out a particular machine learning method b/c of what something "feels like".  Once you become accustomed to which model works best with different types of data, then you can try to focus.  There are more advanced methods and you should investigate multiple learning algorithms.  A good "beginner" advanced one is SVM (support vector machine).  'LibSVM' has bindings to most of the popular programming languages.  Just play around with all the classification methods and their parameters, if they exist.  You may find that you can reduced your dimensions and boost to >99%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [artificial neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network).

### Papers

- [ELECTION RESULT FORECASTING USING TWO LAYER
  PERCEPTRON NETWORK](http://www.jatit.org/volumes/research-papers/Vol4No11/2Vol4No11.pdf)  by G. S. Gill
- "Using Self Organizing Maps to Analyze Demographics and Swing State Voting in the 2008 U.S. Presidential Election" by Paul T. Pearson and Cameron I. Cooper

### Tools / Libraries

To create, train, test and evaluate neural networks you can use a couple of libraries:

- [Google TensorFlow](http://martin-thoma.com/tensor-flow-quick/) (Python and C++)
- [Lasagne](http://lasagne.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) (Python)

Answer (score 1):

For Naive Bayes you can discretize your continuous numerical properties.

For example, for "% Owner occupied housing" you split all 100% scale into ten partitions(0-10%, 10-20%, ..., 90-100%) and get the frequency table.

For some properties you can move to binary values: Unemployment rate < 30% - yes/no.

Good luck in learning Machine Learning :)

Comment: What would you say are the pros and cons of using this method versus using an artificial neural network? For one, I think your method seems simpler. However, it does seem like "a lot of work" to discretize all of my continuous numerical properties. I'm not sure if it is worth it/will be more accurate than the other method.

Comment: I told you how you can use Naive Bayes for your problem. I wasn't going to compare different methods of Machine Learning.